# Robot framework Need same inner text value to be used in 2nd test case

Tags: python, robotframework

Need same inner text value to be used in 2nd test case

**TestCase1**

```
${ClientName} =  get text    //div[@class='row details-box']/div[1]/div/h6
[Return] ${ClientName}
```

**TestCase2**

```
click element  //div[text()=' ${ClientName} ']
```

The 2nd test case value always comes as `//div[@class='row details-box']/div[1]/div/h6` instead of value inside `${ClientName}`.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

You can call [Set Suite Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) to make a variable visible in all test cases within a test case file.

```
*** Test Cases ***
TestCase1
    ${ClientName} = get text //div[@class='row details-box']/div[1]/div/h6 
    Set suite variable  ${ClientName}
```